# How to calculate 95%CI of basic reproduction number from an available (linear) equation?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I am working on my thesis and Prof. asked me to add 95%CI on the basic reproduction number R0, but I don't know how to do in R.

As I have an equation:
R0 = Re/(1-p*VE)

where: R0 is the basic reproduction number to be estimated; Re: Effective reproduction number (I have already estimated at 1.27 (95%CI: 1.22 - 1.33)); p: vaccination coverage (p = 0.946);  VE: vaccine effectiveness (VE = 80.19% (95%CI: 70.41-89.98))

I have not much exposed with statistic, please help me with this.

Comment: How many `R0` values do you have, and is their sample distribution nearly normal? Can you share the computations you used to get the confidence intervals you show in your Question? // Why are you finding CIs for `Re` and and `VE` without question, but puzzles how to get CIs for `R0`? Answer to that might help us know what you're really asking. I note your CIs are symmetrical about point estimates; are data symmetrical?// Depending on data type ans sample dist'n, there are many useful kinds of CIs, including ones obtained through bootstrapping. But it is important to choose wisely among them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.
My objective is to estimate R0 based on surveillance data (daily reported cases) and vaccine coverage data.
Re is estimated in the exponetial phase of the outbreak (using R0 package): Here Re is assumed to be Possion distribution.
VE is from literature and vaccine coverage p is from my vaccine coverage data.

Based on the above numbers, I can only compute that R0 = 5.26 but I do not know how to calculate 95%CI from it.

I am still looking for solution though.
Please let me know if I have reached your questions. Thanks very much.

Comment: If Re is the true effective reproductive number, it would be surprising for it to be Poisson-distributed; why should Re be restricted to integer values?

Comment: Dear Ben Bolker, Thank you for your comment. I followed the approach https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18058829/ to calculate the reproductive number in the exponential phase of the outbreak, Because my population is not naive for measles, so the reproductive number in my calculation is the true Re (but not R0) as in my understanding. In this approach, they assume the reproductive number is Poisson distributed. However, supposing we have a naive population for measles, what is R0 for that population given that we have Re, VE, and p as I mentioned above?. I hope I understand your question right.

Answer (score 1):

From what you say in your Comment, I am not sure what the distribution of
`R0` might be. Certainly, I see no reason to suppose the distribution would
be symmetrical.

Suppose you have $n = 30$ observations as in my fictitious data vector `x`, summarized below:

```
summary(x)
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
 0.03995  2.73616  7.92256  9.38491 16.43023 30.52458 
boxplot(x, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Data are obviously skewed, and a normal probability plot below
is far from linear, so t and Wilcoxon CIs for (population mean
and median, respectively) are inappropriate.

```
qqline(x, datax=T, col="blue")
```

[image]

So I will make a simple quantile 95% confidence interval for the population mean $\mu,$
which makes no assumptions about the population except that it does have a mean.
The procedure is to taka a relatively large number of re-samples of size $n=30$ with replacement from `x`, find the mean `a.re` of each re-sample, and take quantiles
$.025$ and $.975$ to be the endpoints of a 95% bootstrap confidence interval $(6.57, 12.35)$ for $\mu.$

```
set.seed(2021)
a.re = replicate(10^4, mean(sample(x, 30, rep=T)))
quantile(a, c(.025,.975))
     2.5%     97.5% 
 6.571277 12.353882 

hdr = "Bootstrap Dist'n of Resampled Mean"
hist(a.re, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main=hdr)
 abline(v = c(6.57, 12.35), col="maroon", lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

This is a random procedure, so I have shown the 'seed' used in the procedure.
If you use the same seed and data I did, you will get the same result each time
you run the program. Also, two additional runs with different seeds gave
CI endpoints that are the same when rounded to two places.

> There are
> many different kinds of bootstrap CIs. This particular method is easy to
> understand and I have gotten reasonable results using it. Because I simulated the fictitious data I know that the population mean is $\mu = 10,$ which is included
> in the resulting CI. I also know that the fictitious data are exponentially distributed. The procedure below is based on the exponential distribution and is
> known to be an appropriate one for such data. [The the quantity $\bar X/\mu \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(n,n)$ for a sample of size $n.]$ The resulting CI $(6.76, 13.91)$ is similar to the bootstrap CI.]

```
mean(x)/qgamma(c(.975,.025), 30, 30)
[1]  6.760025 13.909833
```

*Notes:* (1) If your `R0` data are *extremely* skewed, or if you have less than a dozen values, then please leave a Comment and one of us may have additional suggestions.

(2) The fictitious data used above was sampled in R, using the following code. Use the same seed and you will get the same `x`.

```
set.seed(1234)
x = rexp(30, .1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BruceET. 
However, I need more time to understand your instruction. I will let you know for more information about this. 
Again, thank you very much.

Comment: Leave comment. Anything I can explain immediately to get you started?